# Application bundled with JRE use which cacerts

Tags: java, bundle, install4j

If I bundle a jre with my application through install4j. Then, does the application refer to the cacerts keystore present in the bundled JRE or the one present on client machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the cacerts of the bundled JRE. The application is running with the bundled JRE, no parts of an installed JRE are involved.